# Return Windows Live ID email address from access control namespace claim

Tags: claims-based-identity, access-control, windows-live-id

I have been configuring my access control namespace for an azure application with the identity providers and have been able to return an email address from Google and Yahoo using their claims tokens but using Windows Live ID the only identifying value I can find is this:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: gX5FDH7dCnWGUfe46CwiCSvRUosc2aM7kmMHBnjQOxM=
```

I know that this represents the email address but I have no means of knowing how '**gX5FDH7dCnWGUfe46CwiCSvRUosc2aM7kmMHBnjQOxM=**' relates to the emailaddress stored value that I have in my database on registration by the user, this is causing me a YSoD as the user cannot be found. I read something that this could be transformed to an email address using Windows Live Connect tools but I was unable to find any further information.

Anyone aware of how this can be done in c# code behind?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some code samples for what you are looking for here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx

I think you need to request a token for the **wl.basic** scope to get an access token that contains the user email address claim.

So according to the link, one way to do this would be like this:

```
private async void btnGreetUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();
        LiveLoginResult initializeResult = await auth.InitializeAsync();
        try
        {
            LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
            if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                LiveConnectClient connect = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);
                LiveOperationResult operationResult = await connect.GetAsync("me");
                dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    this.infoTextBlock.Text = string.Join(" ", "Hello", result.name, "!");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error getting name.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (LiveAuthException exception)
        {
            this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error signing in: " + exception.Message;
        }
        catch (LiveConnectException exception)
        {
            this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error calling API: " + exception.Message;
        }
    }
    catch (LiveAuthException exception)
    {
        this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error initializing: " + exception.Message;
    }
}
```

So you pass the scope as a string array, and instead of using the wl.basic scope you have to use, the wl.emails scope, to get access to the email info, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx#wlemails

Comment: I dont understand how I can assign the scope I have looked at this